# How to connect a single hot wire in a double-bus circuit panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I'm replacing the ancient, decrepit circuit panel in my old RV with a new Square-D HOM612L that has two hot buses:

[image]

The problem is that I only have one hot wire coming in (the standard 30-amp plug found on most all RVs). Every tutorial/example for wiring a 30-amp subpanel that I'm finding starts off with an assumption of four incoming wires—two hot, one neutral and one ground. That's not the case here. I only have three to work with.

I propose to use a heavy jumper wire between the two, but I don't know whether that's safe or allowed.

How do I activate both buses?

Comment: Actually a lot of RVs come with 50A/240V plugs, and use both phases. However all loads are 120V, so they can plug into the smaller TT30 sockets.

Comment: The standard for Rv’s is 30amp 120v OR 50 amp 240, code is slowly requiring tv parks to increase the 50a site capability as of the 2020 code an RV park is required to have 70% 30 amp and 20% at 50amp. And each site will have a standard 120v 20a receptacle per the NEC 551.71.A B & C. Or new updates are required to meet this %.

Comment: @EdBeal — Gotcha.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica — That's good to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can't do is: incoming hot and jumper wire under one hot screw and other end of jumper wire to the other hot screw. Generally only ground screws in panels are designed to take two wires.

With 30A it is easy to add pigtails. Take two short pieces of 10 AWG black or red (anything but white or green) wire and connect to the incoming hot with a wire nut. The other end of reach wire goes to a hot screw.

This method does not work well with big wires on big panels. But at 30A all you need is 10 AWG and wire nuts are fine.

Answer (score 7):

Well, if you are clever, you can run the wire *through* the lug on the left, and then over to the lug on the right.   You would have to scrape off the insulation right where the wire will contact the lug.  The wire between the lugs must be insulated.

Note that your assumption is a little off; larger RVs use a NEMA 14-50 connection, which is 50A/240V.  All on-board appliances are 120V, however, so they can plug into the smaller NEMA TT30 socket with an adapter (they just have to be careful not to run too much stuff).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. (BTW, I would have preferred this method if my incoming wires were long enough. Alas, they aren't. So if I'm going to have to wire-nut an extension I may as well do the pigtail trick.)

Answer (score 2):

Two wires under one lug is a no no. get a red or blue wire nut and connect two pieces of #10 AWG Cu to your incoming feed and connect the two pieces to the two hot lugs.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- Jack's referring to wire-nut sizes by the color of the nut here